# Delegate object exists in target view controller before it's set but is 0x000.. after it's set. Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uistoryboard

I am driving myself crazy over what I am sure is a basic error but I just can't find it. I have simple delegates and everything works except this one. I can't see any difference from the way I normally handle things.

```
@interface MasterViewController () <DetailViewControllerDelegate, SettingsViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation MasterViewController

....

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSettings"]) {
    // here settingsViewController._delegate is 0x075...
    // why? where is this coming from?
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    // here settingsViewController._delegate is 0x00000 which I would expect
    [settingsViewController setDelegate:self];             
    // here settingsViewController._delegate is still 0x0000 -- why?
  }
}
```

Comment: I bet you're using ARC and you need to set your delegate designation to "`strong`".

Comment: ARC is unlikely the cause, since the delegate in question is `self`. Most `delegate` properties should be weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. That took way too long. I've learned my lesson. Thanks Jon for reminding me to use the debugger!

```
    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [segue destinationViewController];        
    NSArray *childViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[settingsViewController childViewControllers]];
    [[childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
```

It works, but is this the right way to do it? [segue destinationViewController] was a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the backing iVar for -[SettingsViewController delegate] is _delegate? You may have an @syntehsize delegate; line which would cause the iVar to be just 'delegate'. Try "p * settingsViewController" in the debugger after the call to setDelegate: and make sure you don't have more instance variables that you think you have.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that `[segue destinationViewController]` is `nil`. Alternately, it is possible that you have a custom `setDelegate:` that is incorrectly implemented.